# firebase assign a key to a specific browser instance when created?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm experimenting with Firebase/javascript and am wondering how do I assign a key to a specific browser instance when created?

- Upon entry, user is greeted with a user input field for their name  and submit button
- When the submit button is clicked the user information is sent to firebase and saved under a newly created key

  I know how to do this and how to retrieve the data from firebase but,

how do i ensure the key that is created gets assigned to the specific user so that only the information in that key is sent back to the user or updated?

I am trying to do this without having a user signup or login. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to identify a device, or an actual person (who may be using multiple devices)?  Are you using Firebase Authentication?

Comment: not using firebase authentication on purpose for this exercise. i'm using push method to create a unique key when a user opens the page and submits the information. I'm trying to figure out how to get that user to gain access to the key via something like thisvar user2938 = ref.child("players").child("-KGb1Ls-gEErWbAMMnZC").child('age');

Comment: If you generate an id on the client, you will have to figure out a way to persist it so it can be reused when needed.

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the submit button, you will send the name and the key to the database:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();
 var reference = ref.child('users');
 var post = reference.push();
 post.set({
   username:name

 });
```

Then after that you will have this in the database:

```
users
  pushkey
    username: userx
```

another user adds his name and clicks submit:

```
user
 pushkey <--- this key will be only to this user
   username: userx
 pushkey1 <--- will be only to usery
   username:usery
```

Comment: what you are saying is correct but how do i get the unique key that is created and associate it with the current user? something like this: var user9823 = ref.child("players").child("-KGb1Ls-gEErWbAMMnZC").child('age');

Comment: @user5640752 what do you mean it is already associated with a user. But if you want to get the key from the database do a listener and retrieve it like this `var name = snap.key;`

Comment: @user5640752 please upvote the answer if it helped you, thank you!

Comment: will have to test this have not returned to this problem but will do so this week :-) and let you know.